# Como faço para que o Html.LabelFor() mostre um asterisco em campos requeridos?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu quero que os campos obrigatórios (propriedades com o atributo `Required`) renderizem com um asterisco indicando que é um campo obrigatório.

```
public class Foo
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Html.LabelFor(o => o.Name) // Name*
```

Como posso fazer isto no MVC 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A única forma que conheço de fazer o que queres é escrevendo um helper próprio, por exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication.Extensions
{
    public static class LabelExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString LabelPara<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
            var htmlAttributesDict = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

            string labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText)) return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            if (metadata.IsRequired) labelText = labelText + "*"; // aqui estamos adicionando o asterisco

            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("label");
            tag.SetInnerText(labelText);
            tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributesDict, replaceExisting: true);

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
    }
}
```

Deve funcionar também para versões anteriores ao MVC 5.

P.S.: Pode ser mais apropriado adicionar uma classe indicando que o campo é requerido e adicionar o asterisco via CSS; fiz colocando diretamente o asterisco para deixar o exemplo mais simples.